# Tag unficiation: [tag:microsoft-office]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We've had [microsoft-powerpoint](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) for a while, and I see the use of that tag. However, yesterday [microsoft-excel](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) popped up in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53248/top-and-bottom-cell-insets-default-value-in-excel-imported-table). I edited it out in favour of [microsoft-office](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office).

This makes me think: should we unify [microsoft-powerpoint](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) (29 questions), [microsoft-excel](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) (now 0 Qs) and the hypothetical [microsoft-word](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) into [microsoft-office](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)?

Comment: Might 'office-suite' be more universal? Otherwise other office tasks like Google Docs and Open Office might need separate tags, when the workflow is similar for all. All other tags could be mapped to it, so users don't even have to choose it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I created the Excel tag yesterday. I think it is as valid as Word and Powerpoint tags. "office" is not a very descriptive tag.

We have individual tags for each Adobe application, not only a blanket "Creative Suite" tag.

So why should Adobe apps get individual preference and not Microsoft apps? IF a question, like the one you pointed out, is specific to Excel in conjunction with InDesign, it deserves to have both those individual tags. A question displaying [adobe-indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign) and [microsoft-excel](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) is much more descriptive and specific than a question just displaying [adobe-creative-suite](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-creative-suite) and [microsoft-office](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)

The "package" sold by manufacturers are largely irrelevant, it's the individual apps that questions refer to. So, to me, the individual tags mean **a lot** more than the package tags. If any tags are to be removed, I'd think the "package" tags offer the least amount of use and are merely "filler" tags. If you are adding tags, you start with the app name generally, not the manufacturer. So starting with "exce" is *not* going to bring up the "office" tag.

Also... adding the Excel tag means nothing if it is never used by anyone else. But clearly the Word and Powerpoint tags *have* been used.

Comment: All true and I agree, I was considering it on the basis that we don't want to encourage these questions. By limiting the applicable tag, we would be far less accommodating to such questions. What do you think on that angle?

Comment: Well, any *design* question that refers to these apps would be okay... if it's not a *design* question it would be off-topic regardless of the tags.

Comment: FYI: [tag:microsoft-word] doesn't exist (yet), it's a hypothetical extension.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with what Scott says in his answer, it isn't referencing the issue at hand all that much.

The thing is, the tag shouldn't have been created in the first place. The question is poor/off topic, i.e. not about graphic design, and should be closed. Creating a new tag that may encourage more off topic questions isn't something that should be done, especially when the question it's being created for is off topic itself - it shows that the tag isn't necessary (at least at the time being).

If a good, on topic question comes later on that is about design and the specific to the Microsoft application, sure, consider creating/adding a tag for it. Otherwise, leave them not created as there is no need for them (at least yet).

Comment: Actually, I see that question as **on** topic. While worded a bit poorly, it is seeking to solve a *design* problem encountered due to inter-application use. It's not *really* asking how to alter software. It's asking for "best practices" when importing Excel data into InDesign.

Comment: @Scott Setting preferences in a program is a graphic design issue? I can't agree with that

Comment: While yes, that's how the user worded it.. what's *really* being asked is "How can I get Indesign to set and retain minimum cell amounts when importing Excel tables." This would be inline with things like using paragraph styles or object styles. Yes it's *somewhat* software support, but support to solve a workflow issue doing design. That, to me is different than software support because you A) don't know the application or B) there's a technical problem with an application. It's a grey area. I'm not saying I'm emphatically right... just how I perceive it.

Comment: In any event, I think the Excel tag has merit and should be allowed to sit. As I posted, if it's never used again, it'll die on its own.

Comment: ..... I've reworded the question to help possibly.